# Proving any polygon in-degree and out-degree vertices equal to 2

Tags: graph-theory

You are given a polygon with arrows on its sides. Prove that the number of vertices with in-degree equal to 2 is equal to the number of vertices with out-degree equal to 2.

Comment: What have you tried? Do you have any ideas? How much graph theory experience do you have?

Comment: @BobKrueger I'm a beginner. I took some examples of polygons and saw that this is true. However, I have no clue how to prove this.

Answer (score 1):

As a possible hint let me say that the sum of the indegrees of all the vertices equals the sum of the outdegrees of all the vertices. Subtract off from both sums those vertex with indegree and outdegree both 1. You should be able to argue to your desired conclusion from here.

Answer (score 0):

It is obvious that a polygon with all arrows arranged head to tail will have in-degree 1 and out-degree 1, making the number of out- and in-degree 2 vertices both $0$.

Given a polygon with any arrangement of arrows, it is obvious that you can construct this polygon by reversing a series of sides in the original polygon.

Each time an arrow is reversed, it will be in one of $8$ possible arrangements relative to the two adjacent arrows. We must simply show that every possible reversal conserves the equality of number of in-degree 2 and out-degree 2 vertices.

The the $8$ arrangements are:

$\rightarrow\rightarrow\rightarrow \implies \rightarrow\leftarrow\rightarrow$, which adds one in-degree 2 vertex and one out-degree 2 vertex,

$\rightarrow\rightarrow\leftarrow \implies \rightarrow\leftarrow\leftarrow$, which does not change either number,

$\rightarrow\leftarrow\rightarrow \implies \rightarrow\rightarrow\rightarrow$, which removes one in-degree 2 vertex and one out-degree 2 vertex,

$\rightarrow\leftarrow\leftarrow \implies \rightarrow\rightarrow\leftarrow$, which does not change either number,

and their mirrors.

Thus, every polygon as described will have equal numbers of in-degree 2 and out-degree 2 vertices.